# User Name display as after login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I want to display logging user name. But below given code working perfect but the same page only working. I want home.php to display.

**Login.php**

```
if($check_user>0)
{
$_SESSION['user_name']=$username;
echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
}
```

**Home page coding** 
   `<?php echo($_SESSION['username']); ?>`

But this code undefined index error showing.
How can call session username in home page

Comment: That also  not working.
Error showing 
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: undefined variable _SESSION. what can i do

Comment: Aside of the question. Why do you redirect with javascript?!

Comment: post full code. where you start your session and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined index because you setting `$_SESSION['user_name']` and try to read `$_SESSION['username']`. Change your home page code to: `<?php echo($_SESSION['user_name']); ?>`

Comment: Thanks But Now undefined variable for _SESSION

Comment: Add `session_start();` at beginning of both files.

Comment: both files added. But Not working any one help me give correct code

Comment: In that case you must have error somewhere else. There is no way that $_SESSION is undefined since it's superglobal variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Bot file add session_start then working.